# Finding a parametric curve

Tags: calculus, parametric

The parabola y=x² is parameterized by x(t) = t and y(t) = t². At the point **A** (t,t²) a line segment **AP** 1 unit long is drawn normal to the parabola extending inward. Find the parametric equations of the curve traced by the point **P** as **A** moves along the parabola.

[Best picture i could come up with](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kp5wxcbpnt)

Comment: This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve#Parametric_curve will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parabola can be parametrised by $\gamma(t)=(t,t^2)$.

The unit tangent vector is given by $${\bf T} = \frac{\dot{\gamma}}{\|\dot\gamma\|}=\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}, \frac{2t}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}\right)$$
The unit normal vector is given by rotating this anti-clockwise by $90^{\circ}$:
$${\bf N} = \left(\frac{-2t}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}} , \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}\right)$$

The curve you're interested in is an example of a [wave front](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1707-11.pdf). They are given by $\gamma + \lambda {\bf N}$
$$\gamma + \lambda {\bf N} = \left(t-\frac{2\lambda t}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}} , t^2+\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}\right)$$
for different values of $\lambda$. In your case, you have $\lambda  = 1$.

An interesting result says that a wave front is singular at $\gamma(t_0)+\lambda{\bf N}(t_0)$ when $\lambda = 1/\kappa(t_0)$, where $\kappa$ is the curvature of $\gamma$, i.e. when $\lambda$ is a [radius of curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature).

Comment: Alright i understand where everything but the square root denominator. I can see why it must be used because t - 2t is moving the x coordinate too much. I just can't see why it is that value instead of something else. I have sketched out my little triangle to try and picture it but i can't see it.

Comment: The square-root denominator makes the vector have length one. For example: what is the length of the vector $(1,2)$? We use Pythagoras to get the length as $\sqrt{1^2+2^2} = \sqrt 5$. So the vector $(\frac{1}{\sqrt 5},\frac{2}{\sqrt 5})$ is in the direction of $(1,2)$, but has length one. The velocity vector of the curve will have different lengths at different places, so we find its length (as a function of $t$) and divide by it so ${\bf T}$ has length one for all $t$ and then the normal ${\bf N}$ has length one for all $t$. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, i kind worked on it a little more and realized that it is almost like a ratio and treated as such. But thanks for the explanation i feel much more confident about my response.

Answer (score 0):

According to your picture you're on the right track.  Add to each point $(t,t^2)$ the normalized normal vector $(-2t,1)/\sqrt{4t^2+1}$ so that the equation of the parallel curve is given by
$$(t,t^2)+(-2t,1)/\sqrt{4t^2+1}=\left(t-\frac{2t}{\sqrt{4t^2+1}},
t^2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4t^2+1}}\right).$$

A hard question without having been teached to deal with vectors.

Comment: I do not think that i totaly understand stand adding the normalized vector ( never took a vector class up to this point). (-2t,1) looks like a ordered pair to me so how can i divide it by the bottom expression and then add it to the points? Do i do -2t divided by the bottom expression and add it to (t) and do the same with (1) and add that to (t²)?

Comment: See my edit, please.